# Delete in Cornerstone

Tags: svn, cornerstone

(Admission - I'm not very familiar with SVN, but have been advised to get familiar with it.)

I often delete a file or directory in my working copy. That shows up in Cornerstone as "missing". Committing the working copy leaves these "ghost" files around (I can understand you might want them back one day, but I want them out of the list of active files, at least).

There is a large, red "Delete" button which invites you to, well, delete the ghosts. But on the next commit, I'm informed that the operation can't be completed. And that seems to be that. Selecting "Clean" informs me that the folder is not a Subversion working copy. I can't use my repository any more.

Could anyone please shed some light?

1. How do I handle file deletion in the working copy ?
2. How do I repair my damaged repository ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I think I've had the same thing happen to me. (I'm also new to SVN and using Cornerstone). I've been doing the deleting from within Cornerstone instead of the Finder and that seems to work pretty well, no missing icon. I get a red D icon, then I commit and there's no ghost file or missing ! icon.

I did just try deleting from the working copy directory and that ! missing icon and ghost file hang around, but if I right-click on the ghost file and choose delete, I get the D icon. Then Commit, everything is fine... no more ghost file.

I've been updating my version of Cornerstone. I'm at v2.5.2. Maybe that's something that's been fixed in Cornerstone? I think I remember having the exact same experience as you at 1 point. I think I quit Cornerstone, opened it back up, selected that working-copy, then hit Update and it fixed it, not sure though...